# ebook by David Cox primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to get the following book free online as pdf or djvu.
Primes of the Form $x^2 + ny^2$: Fermat, Class Field Theory, and Complex Multiplication by David Cox

Comment: While you may not be able to get a copy free online, our own Pete Clark once taught a course related to this book and has some very helpful notes here:  http://math.uga.edu/~pete/primesoftheform.html

Comment: Why ask a question who (affirmative) answer can quickly be obtained by an obvious Google search?

Comment: It is on http://nozdr.ru/biblio/kolxo3/m/mt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure it can not be obtained in such a format in a way which is both free and legal. However, I would strongly recommend the book, and would say that it is worth the cost - it should keep you busy for a long time!